Does the Qiskit transpile function preserve the unitary of the input circuit regardless of optimization level?
I am transpiling some circuits using the transpile function by providing my own custom backend, with specific qubit topologies, created using the GenericBackendV2 class. I am trying to understand if the transpile function in Qiskit preserves the unitary of the input circuit, especially with a higher optimization_level parameter setting? It appears the unitaries are preserved only for qubit sizes < 4. I am testing it using both the Qiskit Operator classes built-in equiv() function, as well as comparing the dot product of the input circuit's unitary and output circuit's unitary to identity. A small sample of the code I am using is given below:
from qiskit.quantum_info import random_unitary, Operator
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
import numpy as np
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import GenericBackendV2

for n_qubits in range(2, 7):
    uop = random_unitary(2**n_qubits)
    qc = QuantumCircuit(n_qubits)
    qc.unitary(uop, list(range(n_qubits)))

    # Generate a circular ring qubit topology
    coupling_map = [[i, i + 1] for i in range(n_qubits - 1)]
    coupling_map += [[0, n_qubits - 1]]
    
    backend = GenericBackendV2(
        num_qubits=n_qubits, basis_gates=["id", "rz", "x", "sx", "cx"], coupling_map=coupling_map
    )
    qctr = transpile(qc, backend=backend, optimization_level=3)

    qctrop = Operator.from_circuit(qctr)

    uopadj = uop.adjoint()
    prod = uopadj.dot(qctrop)
    I = np.eye(2**n_qubits)
    mat_equal = np.allclose(I, prod.to_matrix())

    print('n_qubits:', n_qubits, 'preserved:',uop.equiv(qctrop), 'mat_equal:', mat_equal)

